# How can i alter the order of networks in the Network & Sharing center?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I have a curious issue.  When connected to wifi via my 5ghz radio I get the following.
[image]

However when I connect to my 2.4ghz radio, this is the result.
[image]

I'd like to get the 2.4 situated under the ethernet network as in the first image.   I checked 2 other pc's, my backup desktop exhibits the same behavior, whereas my laptop, its reversed.

Ive used powershells Get-NetIPInterface and they all have the same metric's assigned so I'm unsure why the discrepancy.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Does assigning Ethernet a smaller metric help?

Comment: it does not, no matter what radio I have it connected to I have ethernet set as a smaller metric.  Was hoping it was that simple, alas it was/is not.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 and older, the binding order of NICs can be changed by open Network Connections > press Alt > Advanced > Advanced Settings.

**However, This feature was from the Windows 10 product as there are no longer any components that utilize the binding order.**

If you are using multiple NICs and you need to increase the priority a specific NIC has over others, please use command "Set-NetIPInterface" to define the weight for the interface. For more details, please refer to：
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web-insiderplat_pc/cannot-change-network-binding-order-in-windows-10/08d775da-24d6-4b26-96fe-355920e879a0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  Perhaps I wasnt clear enough in my original inquiry.  I did confirm that the ethernet card does have a higher priority metric (lower number) than both the wifi radios via the Get-NetIPInterface and Set-NetIPInterface commands.   Further perplexing is both wifi radios are set to the same metric, yet one appears above my wired network, one below.  I have to imagine this is something in the registry somewhere?